# Questionings about keys and OAuth

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am building a node.js app (script?) that is using [google-auth-library](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs) and there is something that I don't understand.

I have generated the JSON file containing my OAuth2 client id keys using Google Developers Console, and I am using it in my script the following way :

```
const keys = require('../client_secret.json');
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
    keys.web.client_id,
    keys.web.client_secret,
    keys.web.redirect_uris[0]
);

// Generate the url that will be used for the consent dialog.
const authorizeUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: [
        'https://mail.google.com',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    ]
});
```

Then, I am opening the consent dialog, and getting my token back, etc. My app has the will to be open source, so my question is: should I let my client_secret.json file in my repository so other users can use it using their Google account?

Answer (score 0):

The client token must be kept secret: [extract from Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

> After creating your credentials, download the client_secret.json file from the API Console. **Securely store the file in a location that only your application can access**.

Your application will remain open source as authentication is a service not source code.

To manage your secret, I would suggest you to use environment variables accessible via `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE`.

It does exit packages that will make it easy to handle between you different environments, my favorite is [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv). dotenv loads environment variables from a non required `.env` file. You would typically use it in your development environment, you **must not** commit it!
Dotenv do not require the presence of the `.env` file, and won't override an environment variable that is already set anyway. You will have to define the environment variables in production and test environment the way your prefer.

You can also see this [article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-keep-your-secret-keys-safe-secure-8b1a7877d69c)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if I want someone else to use my app ? Would they have to create an app via the Google Developer Console ? Isn't there a more convenient way for them to use my app, just by using the consent screen and then linking my app to their account, without having to generate keys of their own ? I was thinking of a different server who would have the keys, and then serving to the user who would like to use my app an url with the consent screen. Is that the proper way to do it ? OAuth really is hard to get for me !!

Comment: Sorry I did not fully answered your question! I updated my answer. If by "someone else" you mean a developper that use your code on their own infrastructure, then yes will indeed have to create the credentials as well. the best way to handle it to me is dotenv.